# How to rank categorical data based on time factor

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a data frame which has 3 variables i.e. Id, Event and time for each id there can be multiple event happening and for each event date time factor has been added to find out at what time which event happen. My data frame looks like this as below.

| Id | Event | Time(DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS) | Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | event1 | 4/20/2022 1:09:47 AM | 1 |
| 1 | event2 | 4/20/2022 1:12:23 AM | 2 |
| 1 | event3 | 4/20/2022 1:13:35 AM | 3 |
| 1 | event4 | 4/20/2022 1:13:36 AM | 4 |
| 1 | event5 | 4/20/2022 1:13:37 AM | 5 |
| 1 | event4 | 4/20/2022 1:15:17 AM | 4 |
| 1 | event3 | 4/20/2022 5:56:35 AM | 3 |
| 2 | event1 | 4/26/2022 11:19:00 AM | 1 |
| 2 | event2 | 4/26/2022 11:20:05 AM | 2 |
| 2 | event3 | 4/26/2022 11:20:46 AM | 3 |
| 2 | event5 | 4/26/2022 11:20:50 AM | 4 |
| 2 | event2 | 4/26/2022 11:21:50 AM | 2 |

The difference in event can be seconds, minute or hours or days.

My Aim is to based on my Id column I need to add rank order to the events based on Date time factor. So for each Id rank order should starts with 1.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you wanting a Calculated Column or a Measure?

Comment: Hi @JosWoolley, anything is fine as along as I get the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Create two **Calculated Columns**:

*Calculated Column 1*:

```
=
VAR ThisID = Table1[Id]
RETURN
    RANKX (
        FILTER ( Table1, Table1[Id] = ThisID ),
        Table1[Time(DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS)],
        ,
        ASC
    )
```

*Calculated Column 2*:

```
=
VAR ThisID = Table1[Id]
VAR ThisEvent = Table1[Event]
VAR FirstTimeForThisIDEvent =
    CALCULATE (
        MIN ( Table1[Time(DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS)] ),
        FILTER ( Table1, Table1[Id] = ThisID && Table1[Event] = ThisEvent )
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        Table1[Time(DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS)] = FirstTimeForThisIDEvent,
        [Calculated Column 1],
        CALCULATE (
            MIN ( [Calculated Column 1] ),
            FILTER ( Table1, Table1[Id] = ThisID && Table1[Event] = ThisEvent )
        )
    )
```

Comment: Hi Jos, this query works however if the event is repeated it should pick the same category i.e. consider event 4 for ID = 1 it has been repetated twice so it should pick the first category it has assigned. Is it possible to alter my DAX query? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Don't understand, sorry. Perhaps you should amend your table to include your expected results.

Comment: Hello Jos, I have added a new column Output which is my expected output.

Comment: Thanks, but why is the expected result for ID2/Event5 5, and not 4?

Comment: Sorry, again a mistake from my end. expected result for ID2/Event5 should be 4. I have made my changes.

Comment: @Data-7scientist Managed to do it with two Calculated Columns. Perhaps someone else will manage to achieve it with just one.